# Sprite Zooming using JQuery

Tags: jquery, zooming, sprite

Is there a Jquery plugin that will allow me to zoom in on a sprite that is the background image in a ?

I have Googled around but all solutions lead to an image being placed into an image control.

Is it possible at all?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/?

Comment: @JarekMazur Hi, Not yet!  Do you know if it supports Sprites?  Thanks

Comment: And what do you mean by 'sprite'?

Comment: @JarekMazur Hi, a Sprite is a collection of say 10 separate Jpegs that are 'joined' together.  When using the <div> Background Image and position property you can create animation.  I am currently using this excellent library - Spirtely - but it does not support Zooming

Comment: Well I haven't tried it, but a link I posted in a previous comment looks promising for your purpose :) Good luck

Comment: @JarekMazur Hi, It did not seem to work. But it was still a good link. Best..